# cannot get paperclip image by url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have my paperclip images uploaded on local machine/server, but when I try to access it I have `404` code, when I try the same thing on local it works ok. In my `production.rb` I added `config.serve_static_assets = true`. My links looks like `/system/file_docs/documents/000/000/188/original/image.jpeg?1513769406`

Comment: you put `when I try the same thing on local it works ok`. So is this on a production site that you cannot view the images?  If so how are they being stored?

Comment: I can see the files on the server in public folder + path I provided, seems like rails didn't serve static assets

Answer (score 0):

Maki,

I had a similar issue where my images were not showing.  It was due to configuration where i was showing the images through styling:

```
model.attachment.url :style
```

if this is the case try showing the image through img_path

```
<% image_tag model.attachment.url %>
```

Check your model to see how you are trying to show the images